# How to add custom data in RTSP Video Server?

Tags: rtsp, rtsp-client

I developed the RTSP server camera for 640x480 resolution. Its working fine and showing video in VLC Player. Now I am trying to implementing the custom data(user parameter i.e frame count,timestamp etc.) by considering 640x481 resolution. In this what i am doing is I am considering 640x480 resolution for compression(RGB to MJPG) that means without considering the last line(which is having custom data). I don't know how to add and send  the custom data through RTSP?Please suggest any ideas to implement this.
Thanks.